# Having trouble using useState() with event listeners. Can't see updated state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Unfortunately, I'm stuck mixing a bit of jquery on one of my components (until I finish my custom emoji plugin).

I have a jquery emoji library that creates a content editable div in place of a textarea. In order to get the user input within the editor, I listen on the editors `change` event and set state accordingly, and utilize the state setter within the listener. The problem is, I'm not seeing my state update. Here's the code:

```
const [newComment, setNewComment] = useState('');

    const logComment = function(event) {
        if (event.key == 'Enter') {
            console.log(newComment);
        }
    }

    const setComment = function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
        setNewComment($(this).val());
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setNewComment('hey');
        const id = props.blurtId,
              $wysiwyg = $('#' + id).emojiarea({
                button: '#emoji-btn' + id
            });

        // Calls method to set comment state.
        $wysiwyg.on('change', setComment);

        // Logs state to console when user presses enter.
        window.addEventListener('keydown', logComment);
    }, []);
```

`$(this).val()` logs to the screen correctly on each `change`. However, when I press enter, it just logs the initial blank value to the screen as if the state was never updated.

NOTE: Also, I tried just setting the state to 'hey' at the beginning of `useEffect` and still I get no apparent state update.

Comment: You have `$wysiwyg.on('change', setComment);` did you meant to use `setNewComment` instead?

Comment: @Rikin No, not in this case. I have the `change` event calling a function named `setComment` and inside of `setComment` I then call `setNewComment`

Comment: Ok I see, missed that in chasing down your useEffect code, so does that console.log correct value?

Comment: @Rikin Yes, the `setComment` method correctly logs `$(this).val()` However, I can't get the updated state to log anywhere, even with the simple 'hey' update at the beginning of `useEffect`

Comment: working on it, I think its a different mental model using useEffect and hooks that we are missing here.

Answer (score 1):

The functions `logComment` and `setComment` are redefined every time your component is rerendered, this is how hooks with function components work. Since you have no dependencies in the `useEffect` it will use an older definition of `logComment` wich displays an older version of `newComment`.

The `change` and `keypress` events are different effects (one is for logging the other one for settings the state?), you should define an own effect by splitting the code inside your `useEffect(...` in two:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setNewComment("hey");
  const id = props.blurtId,
    $wysiwyg = $("#" + id).emojiarea({
      button: "#emoji-btn" + id
    });

  // Calls method to set comment state.
  $wysiwyg.on("change", setComment);
}, [newComment]);

useEffect(() => {
    // Logs state to console when user presses enter.
    window.addEventListener('keydown', logComment);

    return () => window.removeEventListener('keydown', logComment);
});
```

The other question is if it makes any sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't fix the issue. I'm still getting an empty string logged to the screen, I'm not even getting the initial 'hey' update.

Comment: Also, I'm not really sure what you mean by this: "you should define an own effect for it and clean up afterwards:"

Comment: What do you mean your state does not change? Your state is not rendered in your component, you should provide a full code example.

Comment: This is a slimmed down version, so the logic may seem strange. It's quite simple really. Each keypress updates state, and when the user presses enter, it will post the comment. When I say `the state does not change` I mean that after pressing enter, the `console.log` does not reflect the updated state. For instance, if I type 'new state' in the input, then press enter, it still reflects the initial blank state. The rendered markup is simple and irrelevant so I left it out.

Comment: I'm actually making some progress with this code. The problem now is that the component keeps re-rendering for some reason, causing an issue with instantiating the emoji plugin multiple times. The state updated though!

Comment: If you don't want your component to rerender you should just create a class component, add your `change` and `keydown` listeners in the `componentDidMount()` and prevent rerendering with:

    `shouldComponentUpdate = () => false;`

Also don't forget to remove the listeners in `componentWillUnmount`. Function component with hooks is really not ideal for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Recommended install while using hooks react-hooks eslint plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks

logComment gets defined everytime there's a new render so I separated it outside the component, it still gets redefined but to understand the mental model better, lets work with that as an example

```
const logComment = newComment => event => {
  if (event.key == "Enter") {
    console.log(newComment);
  }
};
```

And in your function component, you add a dependency to `newComment` which updates everytime there's a change in your case its on `setComment`. Also since you are adding an event listener in useEffect, you should clean up by returning the function that removes listener.

```
const [newComment, setNewComment] = useState("");

const setComment = function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
  setNewComment($(this).val());
};

useEffect(() => {
  const id = props.blurtId,
    $wysiwyg = $("#" + id).emojiarea({
      button: "#emoji-btn" + id
    });

  // Calls method to set comment state.
  $wysiwyg.on("change", setComment);

  const newLogger = logComment(newComment);

  // Logs state to console when user presses enter.
  window.addEventListener("keydown", newLogger);

  return () => window.removeEventListener("keydown", newLogger);

}, [newComment]);
```

I created an example that uses click event, somewhat similar to your example code and no other library though: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-wright-funj3

Comment: I'm actually making some progress with this code, except I didn't need to put the method outside of the component.. The problem now is that the component keeps re-rendering multiple times for some reason, causing an issue with instantiating the emoji plugin multiple times. The state updated though!

Comment: Are you using eslint? If so use react-hooks plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks That will save you time to debug stuff, it will guide you on what you might be doing wrong and you can fix it as it recommends. Also are you able to create codesandbox to replicate your code issue?